# Reactjs:'html-to-react' parser error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, html-parsing

I am getting error while using `html-to-react` parser in `ReactJS`

I am getting an error

> " _htmlToReact.HtmlToReactParser is not a constructor".

I have imported the `'HtmlToReactParser'` as

```
import {HtmlToReactParser} from 'html-to-react'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the ES6 style of import you need to import it as

```
import {Parser as HtmlToReactParser} from 'html-to-react'.
```

Which is an equivalent of

```
var HtmlToReactParser = require('html-to-react').Parser;
```

in commonJS  as was metioned in the DOCS

Comment: Glad to have helpd :)